# Time difference between current time and cookie expiation time in asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, time

Here is the code I used to check the time difference between cookie expiration time and current time.

```
HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies.Get("hello");

if (mycookie == null)
{
    mycookie = new HttpCookie("hello");
    mycookie.Value = "Hello World";
    mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
    Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Write("Cookie Not found <br> Time diff : ");
    Response.Write((mycookie.Expires - now).TotalMinutes);
}
else
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Write("Cookie found <br> Time diff : ");
    Response.Write((mycookie.Expires - now).TotalMinutes);
}
```

As you can see, I'm checking whether a cookie exists or not. If does not exist then I create a cookie and print time difference, this works fine and print `20` as expected(when I run this for the first time). If cookie exists, I print the time difference without creating cookie, this is not working(when I run this for second time or page refresh), this prints some negative long number.

Comment: What is unexpected with your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code, this will give what you need

```
HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies.Get("hello");

if (mycookie == null)
{
    mycookie = new HttpCookie("hello");
    mycookie["message"] = "Hello World";
    mycookie["ExpirationDate"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20).ToString();
    mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
    Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Write("Cookie Not found <br> Time diff : ");
    Response.Write((mycookie.Expires - now).TotalMinutes);
}
else
{
    DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(mycookie["ExpirationDate"]);
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Write("Cookie found <br> Time diff : ");
    Response.Write((end-now).Minutes);
}
```

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. You cannot read the expiration date from browser, so you have to add as an attribute to your cookie and then you can read it  (look at `else` part).
2. You are trying to get `(end-now).TotalMinutes` (reason for big number). The problem is, when you get the current time (`DateTime.Now`) it gives seconds and milliseconds as well. So when you try to subtract you will not get whole number in minutes. Therefore use `(end-now).Minutes`.

To understand more try this code.

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(100);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Response.Write("TotalMinutes : " + (end - now).TotalMinutes);
Response.Write("<br>Minutes : " + (end - now).Minutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly subtract one time from another. [`.TotalMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the Difference in minutes. So you can use like this:

```
DateTime end = cookie.Expires;
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
Response.Write((end-start).TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: @ down-voter : Please let me know the reason for the down-vote?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
The Expired attribute is only used by the browser to know when to remove the cookie. It is not sent back to the server so you cannot read it. If you want to achieve this you should store the timestamp inside the cookie value and parse it when it is sent back. See the note on Expires here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

<s>Although you have not specified what the actual problem is I am assuming the issue is incorrect results. Most probably there is an issue with timezones. The cookie expires property can be local or UTC time according to the docs ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires(v=vs.110).aspx )</s>

So you need something like this

```
DateTime end = cookie.Expires;

//needed because ToUniversalTime method assumes Unspecified kind means Local
//while Expires assumes Unspecified means Utc
if(end.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) 
{
    end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(end, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}

end = end.ToUniversalTime();

DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
Response.Write((end - start).TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: Actually it's a part of a big project that I am working on, all what I need is to print the remaining time when a user opens the browser, only once

Comment: Oh sorry, DateTimeKind.Uspecified

Comment: Your updated answer indicates timezone issues. Try using UTC times like in my answer.

Comment: it's not working, look at the question I've changed it, added more information

Comment: Stop using DateTime.Now. Use only Utc and convert before showing it to the user (in this case you are not showing to the user so you do not need to convert). And when I say "stop using DateTime.Now" I mean in any project.

Comment: I tried your code, it's not working, I get a large negative number, when I try to print the `end` I get `01-01-0001 00:00:00`.

Comment: It seems like you cannot do that. The Expires attribute is not sent back to the server. You need to include the timestamp in the cookie value if you want this functionality.